# In Metal, can you reuse buffer argument table indexes during a pass?

Tags: metal

I see example code in which different buffers are put at the same `index` during a single render pass. Like this:

```
renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(firstBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vcount1)

renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(secondBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vcount2)
```

The `index` parameter is an index into the "buffer argument table", which has 32 entries, so the legal values are 0 to 31.

But I also see documentation that says you can't change the contents of a buffer until after the GPU completes its work on the given render pass.

So, is the above code legal and not prone to any timing issues?

If so, I guess that means the limit of 32 is a limit on how many buffers you can use in a single draw call, not how many buffers you can use in a single pass, aka `MTLCommandBuffer`. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the contents of the buffers themselves, meaning the `MTLBuffer` objects. What you can change is which buffers are bound. When you call `setVertexBuffer`, command encoder remembers which buffer you bound there until you bind `nil` or another buffer and every time you issue a draw command (like `drawPrimitives`, or a dispatch command (like `dispatchThreadgroups`) the current bindings are "saved" and you can go ahead and encode new buffers (and also textures).